# How to bind material change to a single animation action?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

I chose objects colour, then fixed its value using `i` key.

[image]

But the colour property was bind globally for the object. It effects all the object's actions. How can I make colour change for a single action, just like rotation property?

[image]

Comment: I think, you can achieve this using drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using ***Drivers***. 
[image]

In my case I used a driver to change the intensity of a color.
[image]

Hover the cursor over the intensity slider, press <kbd>RMB</kbd> and choose the *Add Driver* option.
[image]

Add an *Empty* and place it at the origin point of a *Cube*. Parent an *Empty* with a *Cube* using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>-->Set Parent To-->Object (Keep Transform).
[image]

Go to ***Graph Editor*** and change the *Mode* from *F-Curve* to ***Drivers***.
[image]

Change the *Drivers Type* to ***Averaged Value***.
[image]

Input the previously added *Empty's* name in the *Ob/Bone* box as pictured below. This Empty will now control the intensity of the *Cube's* color. If the error appear, click the *Update Dependencies* button.
[image]

Now specify what kind of the *Empty's* action would have the influence on the *Cube's* color intensity. I've chosen the *Z Rotation*, so anytime I change the Z rotation of an *Empty*, the insity of a color will be changed. The other kind of transformations (like translating or scaling) would not have any influence on color's intensity values.

[image]

Add a *Generator Modifier* and play with the highlighted values to make the transition speed of the color's intesity slower or faster. You can also redefine the initial and end values here.

[image]